# Create an error message for DirectoryNotFoundException in C# instead of crashing

Tags: c#, exception, folderbrowserdialog

I have a program that uses a folderBrowser to locate a file but adds some pre-existing folders to the end of it.

Example:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(@folderBrowser.SelectedPath + "/folder1/folder2/");
```

But if someone doesn't use the folderBrowser (which they should have) and clicked the Go button, the program will crash and throw an exception.



So what I want to do is use a MessageBox.Show to let the user know that they haven't chosen a folder in the folderBrowser and then cancel the button press so they can choose a folder.

Comment: See [try-catch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Comment: Don't enable the go button until they have found a folder...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [try-catch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

```
 try{

     System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(@folderBrowser.SelectedPath + "/folder1/folder2/");
    }
    catch(DirectoryNotFoundException ex)  
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Folder not found")
    }
```